# EditText and Horizontal Line

Tags: android, android-edittext

When we type an input value by using EditText, I want a horizontal line to be placed below my input like phone book application in all mobile phones.

Enter Phone : ___________

I want my input to be placed on this line. How can I do this by using EditText ?

Comment: EditText already exhibits this behavior

Comment: Length of the line gets bigger when length of your input increases. At first there is no line. I want to put a full line at the beginning of the program.

Comment: You have to set width of EditText to either `match_parent` or other value like `100dp`

Comment: @gktg1414 see my answer. You can also achieve this using this way too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Prac"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Practice"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set width of EditText from  `match_parent` to  `wrap_content` line below code

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set width to either `match_parent` or to fixed width like `100dp`

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
/>
```

Comment: just copy paste of my ans very Good

Comment: @NileshRathod I understood the answer to require width to be `match_parent`. While you have written `wrap_content`. Big difference.

Comment: @PriteshVadhiya And you should notice that my answer is in fact copied from my comment which was way before any other answer. And different in itself from the other posted answer

Answer (score 0):

one method is,

make backgroundtint is black colour and set hint like below code

```
 <EditText
 android:layout_width="200dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:backgroundTint="#000000"
 android:hint=" "  />
```

other method is, 
add a view with black background below the editText and background of the editText is make it null.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone answer said set width and height to wrap_content this is the right answer but still their is another way to achieve this lets have a look.

First create a drawable file (myline.xml) which create the line.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:bottom="1dp"
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke
            // You can change width according to your need
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Now in your layout.xml use **myline.xml** in edit text background.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Phone: "
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/myline"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And its done see the output in screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can Try with CustomEditText Like Below code:

```
package com.cj.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * Created by E069099 on 7/20/2017.
 */

public class CustomEdiTextWithLine extends EditText {
    private Rect rect;
    private Paint paint;

    public CustomEdiTextWithLine(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        rect = new Rect();
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2F);

        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setTextSize(20);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //start at the vertical center of the textview
        float top = (getHeight() + getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom())/2;
        //start at the left margin
        float left = getPaddingLeft();
        //we draw all the way to the right
        float right = getWidth() -getPaddingRight();
        //we want the line to be 2 pixel thick
        float bottom = getHeight()- getPaddingBottom();
        canvas.drawLine(0,bottom,right,bottom,paint);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```